# Change background color on hover/click and maintain that color when the button is active

Tags: php, html, css, button, background-color

So I'm trying to make this header switch its background color when hovered over and I want to make the background stay that color when the link is active. Could anyone help me?

```
<a href="<?= cn('statistics') ?>" aria-expanded="false" class="<?= (segment(1) == 'statistics') ? "active" : "" ?>" style='background-color:#222831;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 20px;width: 97%;'>
    <div class="nav_icon_small">
      <i data-feather="home" style='color:#F16638'></i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_title" style='color:#FFFFFF'>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "link is active"? There are states of links, and "active" in the way it is usual understood, means that the user clicked the link but did not yet release that mouse button. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using the active class. Which is good, but if ou are using inline styling, you styling is overwritten by your inline styling. It is called Cascading Inheritance.

more info in link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance